# Whole word matching with dot characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySQL, when searching for a keyword in a text field where only "whole word match" is desired, one could use REGEXP and the [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] word-boundary markers:

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]"
```

For example, when we want to find all text fields containing "europe", using

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]europe[[:>:]]"
```

would return "europe map", but not "european union".

However, when the target matching words contains "dot characters", like "u.s.", how should I submit a proper query?  I tried the following queries but none of them look correct.

1.

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u.s.[[:>:]]"
```

2.

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u[.]s[.][[:>:]]"
```

3.

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u\.s\.[[:>:]]"
```

When using double backslash to escape special characters, as suggested by d'alar'cop, it returns empty, even though there are something like "u.s. congress" in the table

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u\\.s\\.[[:>:]]"
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This regex does what you want:

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl_name
WHERE name REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)u[.]s[.]([[:punct:][:blank:]]|$)'
```

This matches `u.s.` when preceeded by:

- a blank (space, tab etc)
- punctuation (comma, bracket etc)
- nothing (ie at start of line)

and followed by:

- a blank (space, tab etc)
- punctuation (comma, bracket etc)
- nothing (ie at end of line)

See an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb099/1) with edge cases covering above points.

Answer (score 9):

The fundamental issue with your predicates is that `.` is a non-word character, and any non-word character will cause the word boundary test to fail if they follow a start test or precede an end test.  You can see the behavior [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddd11/7).

To further complicate the issue, the flavor of regular expressions used by MySQL is very limited. According to [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), MySQL uses [POSIX-ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) which if you read the chart at the bottom [Regular Expression Flavor Comparisons](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) has very few capabilities where compared to other flavors.

To solve your problem you must create a new regular expression that will replace the functionality of the word boundary so that it will allow non-word characters to be part of the boundary.  I came up with the follow Regular Expression:

```
(^|[^[:alnum:]_])YOUR_TEXT_HERE($|[^[:alnum:]_])
```

This is equivalent to the standard regular expression below:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])YOUR_TEXT_HERE($|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])
```

The regex searches for non-words characters or string boundaries at the start and end of the text.  `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])` matches either start of string, an alpha-numeric character, or an underscore.  The ending pattern is similar except it matches the end of a string instead of the start.

The pattern was designed to best match the definition of word boundaries from [Regular Expressions in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> [Boundaries] match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A
>   word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or
>   followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric
>   character in the **alnum** class or an underscore.

### Test Results

Using the regex above, I came up with a scenario where I test a string that contains non-word characters at the start and end - `.u.s.`.  I tried to come up with a reasonable set of test items.  You can see the results at 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddd11/10).

**Test Data**

```
test string not present:                 'no match' 
missing .'s:                             'no us match' 
missing last .:                          'no u.s match' 
missing first .:                         'no us. match' 
test start boundary word character:      'no.u.s.match'   
test end boundary word character:        'no .u.s.match'   
test boundaries word character:          'no.u.s.match'   
test basic success case:                 'yes .u.s. match' 
test start boundary non-word character:  'yes !.u.s. match'   
test end boundary non-word character:    'yes .u.s.! match'   
test boundaries non-word character:      'yes !.u.s.! match' 
test start of line:                      '.u.s.! yes match'   
test end of line:                        'yes match .u.s.'
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM TestRegex
WHERE name REGEXP '(^|[^[:alnum:]_])[.]u[.]s[.]($|[^[:alnum:]_])';
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddd11/10)

**Conclusion**

All the positive cases were returned and none of the negative ones => All test cases succeeded.

- You can use `[.]` for the period character instead of `\\.` which I find to be somewhat more readable in the context of a SQL expression.
- You can adjust the sets used to define the boundary to be more or less restrictive depending on your desires.  For example you can restrict some non-word characters as well: `[^a-zA-Z_0-9.!?#$]`.

Answer (score 1):

Working example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aa90d/9/0

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u\\.s\\.([^[:alnum:]]|$)"
```

Basically saying that u.s. must be followed by anything that isn't an alphanumeric character, or the end of the string.

You could change `[:alnum:]` to `[:alpha:]` to include results like **This is u.s.5** if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query:

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP ""[[:<:]]u\\.s\\.([[:blank:]]|$)"
```

No need to use `end-of-word` `[[:>:]]` on RHS since you already have a dot after `s`.

Comment: don't you need double backslash to escape special chars?

Comment: I tried anubhava's second suggestion but the result contains something like "UNS C69100".  As for anubhava's first suggestion, it might return something like "u.s.abc",  which is undesirable.

Comment: @user1036719: So you don't want `u.s.abc` but how about `u.s. abc` ?

Comment: Can you try: `"[[:<:]]u\\.s\\.[[:space:]]"` ?

Comment: @anubhava: "u.s. abc" is desirable, if exists.

Comment: @anubhava: `[[:<:]]u\\.s\\.[[:space:]]` would not include something like "abc u.s.", which is desirable.

Answer (score -1):

In the [mysql regexp manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) is a table of special chars and howto escape them.

Doing your query like

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u[.]s[.][[:>:]]"
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]u[[.period.]]s[[.period.]][[:>:]]"
```

will work

Comment: While the link is a useful resource, and this is the only answer that suggests `[[.period.]]`, the period is not a word character, so will never match before a word-end boundary marker.